# Programmatically create a new node from an existing NID

Tags: 7, nodes

Essentially I want to take a node and duplicate it. Take a node ID and programmatically create a copy of the node.
I want to be able to edit the newly created node, and maintain the data on the old node.

Comment: I am aware of creating new nodes on the fly, and populating the values. example: http://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-in-drupal-7/ Just seeing if there was slicker way of going about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On entities, you can use `is_new` to signify a new entity to save, but you still need to unset `nid` (iirc), `vid`, and `tnid` manually. This saves unsetting `log`.

```
$new = clone $node;
$new->is_new = true;
unset($new->nid);
unset($new->vid);
unset($new->tnid);
node_save($new);
```

Interestingly, the node_clone module incorrectly sets the properties to `null`, which is significant for databases that support NULL and DEFAULT separately (e.g. PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 5):

You may be happy with the [replicate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate) which provides an API to do just that for any entity.

As stated in its README file (You'll find more in it) :

**Very basic usage example:**

```
/**
 * Replicate Basic test function.
 *
 * In this example we will suppose that there is a node with nid = 1 we want
 * to replicate.
 */
function replicate_test_function() {
  // Load a newly created node as an entity.
  $entity = array_shift(entity_load('node', array(1)));

  // Duplicate the entity and save the replica.
  replicate_entity('node', $entity);

  // You can use replicate_clone_entity() instead, alter the replica afterward
  // and manually save the entity, but if you want to implement a generic
  // code like adding ' [Replicate]' to the end of every replicated node title,
  // use the API hook hook_replicate_entity_ENTITY_TYPE().
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load your node with `node_load()` and unset the nid and vid and then save the new node with `node_save()`

```
  $nid = 4;
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $new_node = $node;
  unset($new_node->nid);
  unset($new_node->vid);
  node_save($new_node);
```

Comment: @ThroneDigital and again a pleasure ;-) good luck in your projects